# Attention Something went wrong. Log details included

Tags: error, error-message

```
newly installed Magento 2.4.2-p1 (data migrated from Magento 1.9.4)
```

> **Edited on July 29th:**
>
> The problem is the Error message which can be found in this post. We
> initially thought the issue might have been with the spaces in between
> the words of the product SKUs for example *Best Honey In The World*. We
> have since corrected most of these. The problem comes up when we go to
> Catalog --) Products which shows 1981 records. We then select 100
> products per page and use the right arrow to move from one product
> page to another.... When going from page 18 to 19 - it does not load
> the products and gives the Error. I have tried to query our Magento 2
> database to check for missing SKUs as suggested by Pawan in his reply
> below but it returned 0 results. We do still have access to the old
> Magento 1.9.4 database if any queries or anything can be run on there
> to determine which product is causing this. We really need to get to
> the bottom of this as we urgently need to proceed with the Migration
> and this is holding us back.

I checked all the logs again and found the following in **exception.log**:

```
[2021-07-29 10:10:11] main.CRITICAL: No alive nodes found in your cluster {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\NoNodesAvailableException(code: 0): No alive nodes found in your cluster at /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ConnectionPool/StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php:50)"} []
```

**System.log** has the following:

```
    [2021-07-29 10:27:11] main.CRITICAL: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku::execute() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php on line 70 and defined in /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Model/GetSalableQuantityDataBySku.php:62
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php(70): Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute(NULL)
    #1 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(397): Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SalableQuantity->prepareDataSource(Array)
    #2 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(394): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SalableQuantity))
    #3 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(394): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns))
    #4 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
    #5 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/ContentType/Json.php(69): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->getDataSourceData(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
    #6 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/AbstractComponent.php(158): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContentType\Json->render(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing), 'templates/listi...')
    #7 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(91): Magento\Ui\Component\AbstractComponent->render()
    #8 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()
    #9 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', Array)
    #10 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php(51): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
    #11 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure))
    #12 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
    #13 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
    #14 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->execute()
    #15 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #16 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #17 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #18 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #19 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #20 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #21 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
    #22 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(186): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #23 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(118): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor))
    #24 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #25 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #26 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #27 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
    #28 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #29 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
    #30 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
    #31 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
    #32 {main} [] []
    [2021-07-29 10:30:08] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
```

**Debug.log** has the following

```
[2021-07-29 10:27:11] main.CRITICAL: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku::execute() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php on line 70 and defined in /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Model/GetSalableQuantityDataBySku.php:62
Stack trace:
#0 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php(70): Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute(NULL)
#1 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(397): Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SalableQuantity->prepareDataSource(Array)
#2 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(394): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SalableQuantity))
#3 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(394): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns))
#4 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#5 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/ContentType/Json.php(69): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->getDataSourceData(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#6 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/AbstractComponent.php(158): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContentType\Json->render(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing), 'templates/listi...')
#7 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(91): Magento\Ui\Component\AbstractComponent->render()
#8 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()
#9 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', Array)
#10 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php(51): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#11 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure))
#12 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#13 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#14 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->execute()
#15 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#18 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 .....
#21 .....
#22 .....
#23 ....
#24 .....
#25 ......
#26 ......
#27 ......
#28 ......
#29 ....... 
#30 
#31 
#32 
.
.
```

> **Edited on July 23rd**:
>
> We are **not** talking about Magento 1 at all anymore! I have done the
> migration and **I'm strictly working on the new Magento 2.4.2-p1 from
> now on**. I only mentioned Magento 1.9.4 because that's where we
> migrated the data from and that's where I assume where there was
> perhaps nothing in the SKU field then it looks like during the
> migration, the system filled in product names in the SKU fields and
> these have spaces so I suspect this could be the reason for the Error
> but I am not sure really....

I was in products clicking the right arrow. We have close to 2000 products. I clicked to display 100 per page and when I was clicking from page 19 to 20 I got this very generic Error message. I looked in var/log/**debug.log** and it has the following as the last paragraph (probably around the time the Error came up).

```
[2021-07-23 08:19:12] main.CRITICAL: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku::execute() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php on line 70 and defined in /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Model/GetSalableQuantityDataBySku.php:62
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php(70): Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute(NULL)
    #1 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(397): Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SalableQuantity->prepareDataSource(Array)
    #2 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(394): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SalableQuantity))
    #3 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(394): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns))
    #4 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
    #5 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/ContentType/Json.php(69): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->getDataSourceData(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
    #6 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/AbstractComponent.php(158): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContentType\Json->render(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing), 'templates/listi...')
    #7 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(91): Magento\Ui\Component\AbstractComponent->render()
    #8 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()
    #9 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', Array)
    #10 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php(51): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
    #11 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure))
    #12 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
    #13 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
    #14 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->execute()
    #15 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #16 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #17 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #18 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #19 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #20 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #21 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
    #22 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(186): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #23 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(118): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor))
    #24 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #25 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #26 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #27 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
    #28 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #29 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
    #30 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
    #31 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
    #32 {main} [] []
```

This is the last entry from **system.log**:

```
[2021-07-23 08:19:12] main.CRITICAL: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku::execute() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php on line 70 and defined in /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Model/GetSalableQuantityDataBySku.php:62
Stack trace:
#0 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php(70): Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute(NULL)
#1 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(397): Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SalableQuantity->prepareDataSource(Array)
#2 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(394): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SalableQuantity))
#3 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(394): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns))
#4 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->prepareDataSource(Array, Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#5 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/ContentType/Json.php(69): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->getDataSourceData(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#6 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/AbstractComponent.php(158): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContentType\Json->render(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing), 'templates/listi...')
#7 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(91): Magento\Ui\Component\AbstractComponent->render()
#8 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()
#9 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', Array)
#10 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php(51): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#11 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure))
#12 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#13 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#14 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->execute()
#15 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#18 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(186): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(118): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor))
#24 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#26 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#28 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#30 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#31 /home/myWEBSITE/public_html/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#32 {main} [] []
```

Somehow we got about 700 products which have the product name in the SKU with spaces (probably happened during our migration from 1.9.4?) like this:

Best Product in the World

Is that the reason why this very annoying *Attention Something went wrong. Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.* message comes up? **What can be done to fix this?** If the issue is with the SKUs (which I have been manually correcting) - how do I get rid of the Error so that I'm able to continue editing the SKU and is there a way to do this automatically somehow so that I don't spend eternity opening each product, changing the spaces in the SKU for dashes, saving it, opening another product etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

Run following query will resolve your issue if it is null sku related error:
SKU should be empty or string.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET sku='' WHERE sku IS NULL;
```

You can check your corrupted sku and fix that.

if don't get any affected rows for that query.

your SKU has some corrupted data.
check your corrupted sku that is not a string

Or you can replace by:

```
public function execute(?string $sku): array
```

Comment: I ran this and it came back with the following: 4 rows effected. (Request took 0.0027 seconds.) Sorry for not the exact wording - it switched itself to another language by itself. What does this mean? Should be fixed now? I don't see the rows. It just says 4 were effected.

Comment: You can check your corrupted sku and fix that.

Comment: @Allysin Fix or not?

Comment: It is fixed but now I'm getting the following Error when trying to duplicate a product or move one category into another - could that be the consequence of running that command? The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.
To resolve this conflict, you can either change the value of the URL Key field (located in the Search Engine Optimization section) to a unique value, or change the Request Path fields in all locations listed below:

Comment: @Allysin This is default issue happen after migration. You can follow below url.
1. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169352/magento-2-url-key-for-specified-store-already-exists 

2. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132393/magento2-url-key-for-specified-store-already-exists-while-updating-the-existin

or 
URL rewrites / URL key issues you can install "Regenerate Url rewrites" extension by => https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites Please read carefully before install this plugin

Comment: Thank You @SavanPatel. Save my time.

Comment: @Allysin If you have solved the problem with my answer, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1, You have some/any product without SKU (Magento 1 allows it).

When it comes to Magento 2, SKU is required.

Just go through your catalog in M1 OR query database to check for missing SKU and add missing SKU to those products!

Hope the above will help you.

Comment: Hi Pawan - sorry about the confusion. We are NOT talking about Magento 1 at all anymore! I have done the migration and I'm strictly working on the new Magento 2.4.2-p1 from now on. I only mentioned Magento 1.9.4 because that's where we migrated the data from and that's where I assume where there was perhaps nothing in the SKU field then it looks like during the migration, the system filled in product names in the SKU fields and these have spaces so I suspect this could be the reason for the Error but I am not sure really....

Comment: Do the 2 paragraphs from the two log files give any indication? I'm not sure how to read them.

Comment: select entity_id from catalog_product_entity where sku=NULL OR sku='';

Comment: could you plz run above query in m2 db ?

Comment: error seems missing SKU

Comment: I ran it on Magento 2 phpMyAdmin and 0 results. select entity_id from catalog_product_entity where sku=NULL OR sku=''

Comment: What is the command to run in Magento 1? When I put the above in Magento 1 - it says: #1146 - Table  'name1_name2.catalog_product_entity' does not exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127832/discussion-between-pawan-and-allysin).